# Switching to landscape mode within fancytikzposter

Tags: posters, tikzposter, a0poster

Working on a scientific poster and decided to build up on a template created by Elena Botoeva available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/example-demonstrating-the-fancytikzposter-package/vdmkprbshnym). Was able to personalize it the way I want it to look - yet, want to create two versions of the same poster: one portrait and one landscape. As can be seen on examples [here](http://static.latexstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/fancytikzposter.pdf) - they are all portraits... Currently, I am wondering whether it is even possible to achieve a landscape version of this poster. Am aware that fancytikzposter is no longer supported and was merged with TikZposter but not sure what are the consequences of that and if that could possibly affect my attempts.

I have tried a "typical" approach, i.e. added [landscape] in front of {a0poster} but that does not seem to do the trick.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{a0poster}
```

I am open to any suggestions.

EDIT. Replacing

```
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}
```

with this line (switching the dimensions)

```
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=118.9cm, paperheight=84.1cm]{geometry}
```

seems to be working.

Comment: Don't use links to your code - such links changes over time and then are no longer usable. Add a small complete example here.

Comment: tikzposter and sciposter support landscape.  You might try pdflscape with the others.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, actually you gave me an idea! In my case, all I need is to change paperwidth with paperheight in {geometry} package, right? Not sure if it is the "right" way to approach a problem like that but believe it would work in my case.